# CloudWatch log pricing confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have some queries about Cloud Watch Log pricing .

1) As mentioned on pricing page , $0.005 per GB log data scanned by Cloud Watch Logs Insights queries ,  can we fire as many queries as we want , it will charged on basis of "log data scanned by Insights queries" or it will charged on basis of number of queries we fire ?

2) I want to transfer my data from Cloud watch Log to S3 bucket after every 30 days , So transfer out charges will be applicable as Data Transfer out from EC2 instance ?

Answer (score 6):

> 1. As mentioned in the pricing page, $0.005 per GB log data scanned by Cloud Watch Logs Insights queries, can we fire as many queries as we want, it will be charged on basis of "log data scanned by Insights queries" or it will be charged on basis of number of queries we fire?

Yes, you can fire as many queries as you can and it will be charged on the basis of **all the log data scanned by all the insight queries** at the rate of $0.005 per GB log data scanned via CloudWatch Logs.

> 2. I want to transfer my data from Cloud watch Log to S3 bucket after every 30 days, So transfer out charges will be applicable as Data Transfer out from EC2 instance?

CloudWatch logs being transferred to S3 will be charged on the basis of pricing mentioned under **Deliver Logs to S3 Cost** and that is $0.25 per GB for the first 10TB if transferred to S3 via CloudWatch Logs.

For reference, see this image below:

[image]

For more details and **calculating cost**, check out **Logs** tab under **Paid tier** section here: [Amazon CloudWatch pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/)

*Note: Pricing may vary from region to region.*